# How do I increase my file upload limit size for my WordPress instance running on GKE

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have installed a WordPress instance on GKE but cannot upload a new theme for my site, because the max upload size is set to 2MB.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer depends on details not present in your question. For example, which operation system? How is PHP configured? Which version? That determines which php.ini file to modify.

This example is for Ubuntu PHP version 7.4 FPM:

- Edit /etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini
- Change upload_max_filesize = 2M (change to desired limit)
- Change post_max_size = 8M  (change to desired limit)
- Change memory_limit = 128M  (usually not necessary to change)
- restart the server.

In the worst case, you can just modify all of the php.ini files located in the `/etc/php` subdirectories. Make sure you back up each file that you modify.

Note: you have tagged Kubernetes, which means you must modify the containers while being built and not after deployment.